# Stanford CoreNLP NER training freezes

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to train a NER model for Portuguese. I succeeded when training with 10 entity classes. However, with the same training dataset, increasing the entity classes to 30ish it **freezes** after some iterations.

I even increased the RAM up to 30g, but no luck. I used 3.7.0 version of Stanford CoreNLP, and ran the following running command (using the default prop configurations):

`java -d64 -Xmx30g -cp stanford-corenlp.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop "prop.prop"`

Any idea on how to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

@arop,The problem is that the system requires some more heap memory,
What you were thinking the 30gb is not RAM actually, it is the heap size, the memory that the stanford core nlp can use to store the temporary memory.

Increase its size to 100gb and see, based on your hard disk size.

when to try to increase the heap size if the server shutdown's then install the jdk again.